# npm i error "Error: cannot find module 'nopt'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

when I tried to install node modules it threw "Error: cannot find module 'nopt" I try different methods but no one worked. I attached error message in the image below

```js
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "run": "nodemon server.js",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-sagemaker-runtime": "^3.56.0",
    "async": "^3.2.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1019.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.8.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.1",
    "node-schedule": "^2.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serverless-http": "^2.7.0",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "serverless-offline": "^6.8.0"
  }
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What versions of Node.js and npm are you using?

Comment: have you tried removing node modules and package lock and reinstall everything ? clearing npm cache might also work.

Comment: Try fixing your install of node-gyp.

I had the same issue and running this fixed it for me: `npm i -g node-gyp`

Answer (score 0):

Move all the values in "devDependencies" to "dependencies". Then try deleting the "node_modules" that other questioners mentioned. I solved it with her method.

I'm Japanese, so I used Google Translate to create the document. The sentences may be strange.

```json
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "run": "nodemon server.js",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-sagemaker-runtime": "^3.56.0",
    "async": "^3.2.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1019.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.8.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.1",
    "node-schedule": "^2.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serverless-http": "^2.7.0",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "serverless-offline": "^6.8.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wasn't able to run npm because of the **nopt library**. To resolve the issue, I manually created the following directory structure and content at the specified path in Linux:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/
```

You can find the **nopt** library at this link: **[nopt library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nopt?activeTab=code)**

After doing this, the problem was resolved, and now npm is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73870471/npm-i-error-error-cannot-find-module-nopt#comment133736568_73870471) fixed it for me. Run this:

```
npm i -g node-gyp
```

Answer (score -1):

Please, try to remove that package, reinstall it, then reinstall npm

Comment: You should have write this in a comment. This is not a full detailed answer with documentations

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Your `package.json` doesn't have record of `nopt` package so you'll have to install it by running this command in the terminal: `npm i nopt`

Comment: No. When you write a package.json you should only mention immediate dependencies. Dependancies-of-dependancies are handled automatically (in this case by the package.json belonging to the canvas module).